# Is there a function to get the skew diagonal of a matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, diagonal

```
A=[a_11, a_12; a_21, a_22]
```

The skew diagonal is `[a_12, a_21]`. Right now, I flip the matrix around and use diag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an alternative to `fliplr` and `diag`, you can index directly into the matrix like this:

```
A = magic(3);
s = length(A);
idx = s:(s-1):(s*(s-1)+1);
%# for anti-diagonal, use the following 
%#idx = (s*(s-1)+1):(-s+1):s;

skewDiag = A(idx)
skewDiag =
     4     5     6
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be limited to 3x3 matrices? General case?

Comment: No. This is not limited to 3x3 matrices. It is a general solution for ANY size of square matrix. Only the example was 3x3.

Comment: @Jonas: It seems that you are calculating the `anti diagonal` which is not what the OP requested. In some literature the `skew diagonal` is same as yours `anti diagonal`, but OP's example implies it's not the case here. Thanks

Comment: @eat: I'm calculating the "main skew diagonal" (according to the Wolfram site). For a 4-by-4 array, this would be [a41,a32,a23,a14].

Comment: @Jonas: but isn't [4 5 6] the main skew diagonal for magic(3)? Thanks

Comment: @Jonas: OK, now you made my answer superfluous ;-). Thanks